Cloud Fleet Routing - Distance Matrix as an input to the API
I see this on Google webpage: "We provide the flexibility of bringing your own distance matrix using third-party services, which is the default option in the Cloud Fleet Routing Service offered by Cloud Optimization API" but the documentation doesn't show an example of how to provide your own matrix. Anyone has experience with that?
